# Detect Supermicro DIMM (memory) errors as reported during POST without rebooting

Tags: memory, ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool

One of our Supermicro servers reports an error like this during POST:

> Failing DIMM: DIMM location (Correctable memory component found)
>
> DIMMB2

I can also see this in the Health Event Log in the IPMI web interface:

> Failing DIMM: DIMM location. (Correctable memory component found) (DIMMB2)

Until I rebooted it (for unrelated reasons), the server has been running fine, so I had no idea anything was wrong with its RAM. Is there any way to find errors like this without rebooting the server, e.g. some ipmitool command?

If not, is there a way to at least a scriptable way to see these errors *after* a server has been rebooted, i.e. without using the web interface? I tried `ipmitool sel elist`, but it shows these entries as "Unknown" events:

> 5 | 10/11/2019 | 11:21:25 | Unknown #0xff |  | Asserted

**Edit**: I found that Supermicro's proprietary tool, IPMICFG, can show these events (`IPMICFG-Linux.x86_64 -sel list`) but it would still be nice to have a way to do this with `ipmitool` and, most importantly, without rebooting.

Comment: I just saw the same thing - in the same slot.. After restarting everything came back fine.  Ive started a memory test 16 hours ago and so far no errors.  Did you end up hacing faulty memory?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, I realised there is probably no way to have IPMI detect it without rebooting, because it only reports what the POST memory test detected - which runs on boot.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use FreeIPMI instead (ipmi-sel for instance): there's a good chance it will give you more information than ipmitool as the codebase is much more maintained

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and `ipmi-sel` shows `9    | Oct-11-2019 | 11:36:33 | Sensor #255     | OEM Reserved      | Event Offset = 00h ; Event Data3 = 05h`. Better than ipmitool, but not exactly clear. If I'm going to use another tool anyway it might as well be IPMICFG. Anyway, the main problem is detecting this without reboots.

Comment: FreeIPMI maintainer here, sorry late to respond.  The "OEM Reserved" indicates that there are OEM specific things FreeIPMI has to map to get the 00h & 05h into English.  You'll have to specify the --interpret-oem option to get them (assuming FreeIPMI supports those OEM specifics).  In FreeIPMI 1.6.4 a bunch of DIMM mappings were supported in a number of Supermicro motherboards, so a newer version may be worth checking out.